# Ignored call to 'print()'. The document is sandboxed, and the 'allow-modals' keyword is not set Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, iframe, web-applications, google-sites

I need to make window.print (), this worked correctly until yesterday, now it throws me an error in my browser console:

```
Ignored call to 'print()'. The document is sandboxed, and the 'allow-modals' keyword is not set
```

**Google App Script  and Google Site**

Mi code:

```
<button onclick=" window.print()">Print</button>


function doGet() {

 var output= HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).addMetaTag("viewport", "width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no").addMetaTag("mobile-web-app-capable", "yes").setTitle("Reforzados")
return output;
}
```

Who could give me a scope of the possible solution, thanks

Comment: Please look up iframe, the error gives all you need to know.

Comment: @Akxe Thanks for your comment, but in my code, I don't have any iframe tag, I already tried the supposed duplicate question but it doesn't solve it

Comment: You tagged this with iframe but dont have an iframe tag?

Comment: @TomLV Exactly, my code does not contain the tag, just add that tag because I consider the problem to come from that part, if I am wrong please correct me, thanks

Comment: Yes, it is due to iframe sandboxing. Provide the iframe, otherwise, we cannot help you anymore

Comment: Have you  used the script web app in Google sites? Have you tried it in another browser? Can you inspect the html to see the `sandbox` iframe allowed params?

Comment: @TheMaster , 
yes, my application is in google app script, and the app url is in google site, and tested without google site and it works

Comment: @Danna Is this in  the classic Google site or new Google site?

Comment: @TheMaster is the classic Google site , the one drive

Comment: Try directly embeding within iframe using html `<iframe src ="https://script.google.com..."></iframe>` instead of using embed menu

Answer (score 0):

Content-Security-Policy feature, Just add `allow-popups` & `allow-modals` in the SecurityHeadersAttribute file and working fine.